# Child Element 100% size of Parents contents

Tags: html, css

**What i have:**

A Block element with fixed size, but dynamic content size and `overflow: scroll;`.

**What i want:**

A transparent layer over the content, so no matter how far the parent is scrolled the layer covers the content.

**What i tried:**

```
.layer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

inside the parent after the content.

**The issue:**

The layer covers the parent properly, but as soon as i scroll it doesn't cover the content.

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/wYgWh/2/

Red should cover everything, but not too much;

Comment: Make a fiddle please.

Comment: @JimmyRare Done. The layer is supposed to cover everything, no matter where i scroll.

Comment: Beautifully asked... you edit it with all the info and very organize!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Height: 100%;` give the element the same height as it's parent.
The parent you have defined is not as high as the content you want to cover.

If you put the "layer" inside your "content" in your markup, you can then absolute position it relative to the "content". So now the `height: 100%` will relate to the content instead of the "parent" (scroll window).

Also, when you want to position something absolute, that element will relate to it's closest **non-static** parent.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwDhA/).

Comment: Correct Vogel612! I added this in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't work though if `.content` is smaller than `#parent`. And if i define `min-width/height: 200px;` it extends the content unnecessarily. http://jsfiddle.net/mwDhA/1/

Comment: `min-height: 100%;` on `.content` should do it.

Comment: `overflow:auto` on `.parent`. `width: 100%` on `.content`.

Comment: My content is dynamic, why would i set it to a fixed width?

Comment: You mentioned you got scrollbars, so I assumed you did only want to have one on the y-axis if the content was higher than the parent.
Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Ok i guess it was on my part. I did not meant the scrollbar itself but the content being scrollable on the y-axis (too big) when its `min-height` is `100%` but the scrollbar is visible. => height becomes 100% + scrollbar-height and y-axis gets visible aswell.

Comment: I used a javascript handler now to fix the smaller-case. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="coverable">
   <div class="layer"></div>
   Content that gets covered!
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.coverable {
  position: relative;
}
.coverable .layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If i scroll the layer also moves. Same problem as before.

Answer (score -2):

to need to make

```
.layer {
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Afaik fixed will (unfortunately) ALWAYS be relative to the viewport.

Comment: It will also cover my scrollbars and make them useless.